# iOS - when to use run loops?

Tags: ios, nsrunloop

I try to understand run loops. I read through Apple Documentation, through stackoverflow answers and google and still don't fully understand it. I get it that run-loop is an event handler, which starts on user input and handles all events and when run loop is not active the app is sleeping. Am I right with this ?

Main question is - what is the case, when I want to invoke run loop manually, by myself ? For what may I want to do this ?

Comment: when you are doing rendering via OpenGL, only time ive needed one. im sure there are other use cases

Comment: but to be honest i think its quite rare that an app would ever need one. so depends what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: its a very popular question on job interviews

Comment: thats interesting, i guess since it has quite a rare use case that it will indicate the depth of you ios knowledge. well if you want bonus marks, say OpenGL ES uses one in conjunction with a CADisplayLink for syncing rendering to the refresh rate of the screen